# Regex for excluding urls with get parameters

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to exclude urls that contain the keyword category as well as have get parameters.

I managed to do the first part but not exclude the urls with get parameters.

In this example only the first link should be accepted.

Here is a link to the actual regex101: https://regex101.com/r/S1TIbF/2

[image]

Comment: Something like https://regex101.com/r/S1TIbF/3?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, it doesn't seem like it has any difference from the already posted regex :/

Comment: You may try `^(?![^?]*\/category(?![^\/])[^?]*$).*$` then, see https://regex101.com/r/vNbFIN/1. I added `\n` in the regex demo since the test is performed on a single multiline string, while, I assume, these lines represent separate strings.